# Querying data from SQL table basing on other rows values

Tags: mysql, sql

The title sounds a little bit complicated but it's hard to explain what do I mean without an example.

So I have a SQL database with tree tables:

Photos:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| hash       | varchar(256)     | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| path       | varchar(1024)    | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| store_date | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

tags_names:

```
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(64)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| type  | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

tags:

```
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| value    | varchar(2048)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| photo_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`Photos` is a table with data about photos (id, path to photo and sha hash).

`Tag_names` collects info about possible tags (id, name of tag and its type which I map in my program to proper type like string, number, date etc)

`Tags` contains information about which photo contains which tags with tag values:
`name_id` is a reference to tag_names.id, `photo_id` is a reference to photos.id and `value` is value for tag.

The problem I have is that I want to visualize data from database in a tree form.
An example: a root node would have sub nodes which names would be a dates. There will be a "Date" tag in tag_names table, and there will be entries in tags table referencing to this name (by tags.name_id) and different values.

So a visualization of:

```
select * from tag_names;
+----+------+------+
| id | name | type |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | Date |    1 |
+----+------+------+

select * from tags;
+----+------------+---------+----------+
| id | value      | name_id | photo_id |
+----+------------+---------+----------+
|  1 | 2011.05.19 |       1 |        1 |
|  3 | 2011.05.20 |       1 |        2 |
+----+------------+---------+----------+
```

Would be a tree like this:

```
root
|
+--- 2011.05.19
     |
     +---- photo 1
     |
     2011.05.20
     |
     +---- photo 2
```

I can achieve it very easily just with proper query on `tags`.
However I'd like to be able to create two (or more) levels in tree.

Lets say I want date and time in my tree.
I can still gather data from 1st level (finding all possible values for tag with name "Date") but then I'd like to find all possible values of "Time" tag but only for photos which have particular "Date" tag.

So I need to make an `select` on `tags` where tag name equals to "Time" and photo with related `photo_id` also contains tag "Date" with one particular value.

Is it possible with my tables layout?
I can always do it by caching some data which is my last resort, however I'm curious if such a problem can be solved with SQL directly.

**EDIT:**

An example of query on photos (asked in comments) below:

```
'1', 'cda6bfe0fd7a588704e1ebc81f8ef4b3c884895afadf0d0c97892db8f6d9cc91', '/DSCF9529.JPG', '2014-03-23 16:19:26'
'2', 'cda6bfe0fd7a588704e1ebc81f8ef4b3c884895afadf0d0c97892db8f6d9cc91', '/DSCF9529.JPG', '2014-03-23 16:19:26'
'3', 'e213df3f22276173c2e07a8c4ec9e83aee73605196d4e2aa529fbb34ceb6f86d', '/DSCF9532.JPG', '2014-03-23 16:19:26'
'4', '681a7c723ce16908c0fc73ed819de9a1af7c19cbd6fbcb7bf1c238a9d0378c2f', '/DSCF9531.JPG', '2014-03-23 16:19:26'
'5', 'd586eaae7d0fd625ec6282a51d12625db341c72d9395efd9e142850e457272ca', '/DSCF9537.JPG', '2014-03-23 16:19:26'
'6', 'dc1c40ce690c42f9fa9edc0f5020e01ca8e0c59694108d49f942b79b0167ef10', '/DSCF9222.JPG', '2014-03-23 16:19:26'
'7', '518884037e9d67ccbee98f6805cf7bb5ccf4c6f2e7aa35efe3c834e7c7ad3c32', '/DSCF9534.JPG', '2014-03-23 16:19:26'
'8', '21d33a2c5a25515689d68885d7d485aa89b96b7e5929a86ef658e53b61c7266b', '/DSCF9221.JPG', '2014-03-23 16:19:26'
'9', 'ff7ea451ce772b9d18c706dc9b989a1a318491e5d0f095575bf5dd6cc6448ab0', '/DSCF9530.JPG', '2014-03-23 16:19:26'
```

Comment: can you add the query you use to get your first level? -- basically you will have to do a select of that select and join a select where the time has your date tag

Comment: here is my select:
SELECT photos.id, tag_names.name, tags.value FROM tags LEFT JOIN (photos, tag_names) ON (photos.id=tags.photo_id AND tag_names.id=tags.name_id) WHERE name='Date';

Could You give and example? Those are my first steps with SQL

Comment: does that query work? like does it pull out what you want?

Comment: also can you add a few sample rows from a select * from photos? i'm building a sql fiddle to query off of

Comment: that one collects for me all photos which have tag named "Date". And yes, it works I can collect all values. Actually this query is a little bit more complex than necessary for your question (data from `photos` table is not necessary) but in my program I gather more data

Comment: I've added result of `select * from photos` to my question

Comment: and theres different types of tag names right? like "time"

Comment: please verify that this is correct before we move foreword.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a942/2

Comment: I did a little modification - I've changed values for 'Time' tags, and also I've set 'Time' tags to be attached to photo #1 and #2 not #3 and #4

Comment: can you send me the sql fiddle link to the edit? the url changes when you change the schema

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5001a/1

Comment: `So I need to make an select on tags where tag name equals to "Time" and photo with related photo_id also contains tag "Date" with one particular value.` what one particular value are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this query selects all photos with the tag name "DATE" and then selects photos with the same ID that have the tag name "TIME" is this what you want? see [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5001a/13) for working example

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
(
    SELECT p.id AS p_id FROM photo p
    JOIN tag t ON t.photo_id = p.id
    JOIN tag_name tn ON tn.id = t.name_id
    WHERE tn.name = 'Date'
) AS ti
JOIN tag t1 ON t1.photo_id = p_id
JOIN tag_name tn1 ON tn1.id = t1.name_id
WHERE tn1.name = 'Time'
```

Comment: Yeah it works. I've added some more data, to make it more complex and looks like it works. Now I need to try to understand it ;)

Comment: ok let me help :)... first of all you run the inner query. that gets the photos with the tag name "DATE" only. along with those photos is their ID. so I then JOIN the other tables off of the ID related to the photos that only have "DATE" as their tag name. from there you just now say give me the tag name "time"

Comment: when i do `JOIN tag t1` notice that its `ON t1.photo_id = p_id` --- p_id is the alias name I gave the photo_id in the subquery

Comment: so once its linked then you say filter those by "TIME" so now you're on the second level of the tree :)